# Checking if time_t is between other time_t with some margin of error

Tags: c++, time-t

I have two time_t variables: timeA and timeB.

What I want to do is check if timeA is the same as timeB. However, I know that in some cases they won't be exactly the same and there may be a 1 or 2 seconds difference between the two of them, so what I really want to check is:

```
    if (timeB - 2sec) <= timeA <= (timeB + 2sec)
```

Is it possible to do so?

I suppose one option is not to use time_t but instead keep timeB as a tm struct, and just before the comparison, subtract two seconds and create a time_t timeBminus and then add four seconds and create time_t timeBplus. The problem is that I will be comparing several millions of timeA - timeB pairs and want to keep it as simple and fast as possible.

How can I do it?

Comment: You should just try it out and see if it works :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like -

```
if (std::fabs(std::difftime(timeA, timeB)) < 2.0)
```

(Not able to check the exact type etc from here but I think the idea is correct)

Comment: +1, although I would use the `double` overload of `std::abs` instead of C-style `fabs`.

Comment: Indeed, I knew there was something like that but I'm not able to easily check what the functions were called (posting from a phone...)

Comment: Thank you. Seems obvious now!

Comment: `time_t` may not be in seconds.

Comment: Indeed, but the result of difftime is

Comment: Warning: `int abs(int)`, `long abs(long)`, `float fabs(float)`, `double fabs(double)` and `long double fabs(long double)` => it's still `fabs` even in C++ :(

Answer (score 2):

Even though `time_t` usually represents seconds, it is in fact not a standard behavior. The details of `time_t` are left to implementation (According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t))

Instead of using the `time_t`s directly, it is best to use [`struct timespec`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec) and use the `tv_sec` member. To check whether they are in 2s distance from each other:

```
static inline bool close_enough(struct timespec &ts1, struct timespec &ts2)
{
    const int64_t sec_in_nsec = 1000000000ll;
    int64_t ts1_nsec = ts1.tv_sec * sec_in_nsec + ts1.tv_nsec;
    int64_t ts2_nsec = ts2.tv_sec * sec_in_nsec + ts2.tv_nsec;

    return ts1_nsec >= ts2_nsec - 2 * sec_in_nsec && ts1_nsec <= ts2_nsec + 2 * sec_in_nsec;
}
```

or use the same expression in an `if`. The function call will be optimized away, so no worries about that. Using `abs` as suggested in other answers is fine, even though it converts your integers into floating points and performs floating point operations.

#### Update

Using `time_t`, you can use [`difftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/difftime) to get the difference between two times. Again:

```
static inline bool close_enough(time_t &t1, time_t &t2)
{
    double d = difftime(t1, t2);
    return d >= -2 && d <= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(abs(timeA - timeB) <= 2) {
  // yay!
}
```

Comment: For a 2.0 seconds margin, this answer assumes `time_t` resolution is seconds.  A common situation, yet not portable.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports c++11 you should use chrono instead of ctime:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point a,b;

    std::tie(a,b) = std::minmax(a,b);
    if ((b-a) < std::chrono::seconds(2)) {

    }
}
```

This way you know the difference between the times is actually less than 2 *seconds* rather than simply 2 ticks of the clock, where ticks aren't necessarily seconds at all.

Unfortunately there's no std::abs for clock durations, or you would just write `if (std::abs(b-a) < std::chrono::seconds(2))`, although it's easy enough to write your own:

```
template<typename Rep,typename Period>
std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period> abs(std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period> d)
{
  return std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>(std::abs(d.count()));
}
```

Comment: Another new c++ feature I didn't know about. I know all the big features but seem to have missed all the small ones.